# Make current state as starting point for Git in PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

I have a project in PhpStorm. When it comes to Git, I am new to it.
Previously I made some test commits and pushed them into GitLab. I would like to have my current code/state in PhpStorm to be as a starting point.

How do I remove previous commits from PhpStorm and GitLab and have a clean start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care about you previous commits, you can delete the `.git` directory and then `git init` a new repository in your project root. Add all files and then force-push to GitLab, overwriting all other commits. **WARNING**: You will lose all previous commits forever.

If, however, you might still need the old commits, you can create a new fully disconnected branch with `git checkout --orphan new_branch_name` and then committing the current state.

Comment: your suggestions helped. For everyone who may have a similar challenge recommend to do the git commands form command line (`git init, git add ., git commit -m 'Initial'`) not phpstorm,